# Generating a Truth Table

Tags: haskell

If I have some values A B C, is is possible to generate a list of all their possible truth values:
the input is ["X", "Y", "Z"]
e.g. the list contains 8 lists (rows of table)

```
[ [ ("X",True), ("Y",True), ("Z", True) ],
[ ("X",True), ("Y",True), ("Z", False) ],.... ]
```

Are there any hints on how to do this?

I would like to generate a truth table for an arbitrary number of variables.

Answer (score 4):

What you need is not a truth table but rather a cartesian product.
You can obtain what you want using list comprehension: `[(x,y,z) | x <- [True, False], y <- [True,False], z <- [True,False]]`

If you want to keep variable names you can use tuples: `[(x,y,z) | x <- [("X", True), ("X", False)], y <- [("Y", True), ("Y", False)], z <- [("Z", True),("Z", False)]]`

Comment: "What you need is not a truth table" - why it is not a truth table?

Comment: See also: `mapM (\v -> [(v, True), (v, False)]) "xyz"`.

Comment: @lisyarus: the OP simply wants to generate all the possible true/false combinations. A truth table has an additional column holding the values of the function it represents corresponding to the input values in that row.

Comment: @mariosangiorgio Totally forgot what a truth table actually is. You convinced me, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Let the recursion be with you. If you have a truth table for `n` variables, you can obtain one for `n+1` variables (with added variable `X`) by appending first `(X, True)` to the table for `n` variables, and then appending `(X, False)`.

```
truthTable :: [String] -> [[(String, Bool)]]
truthTable [] = [[]]
truthTable (x:xs) = (map ((x,True):) ts) ++ (map ((x,False):) ts) where ts = truthTable xs
```

Comment: could you explain the last line? I am a newbie at Haskell. Also what is the : in ((x,True):) ? I thought that is used to concat results but there is nothing after it? Also what is the map for?

Comment: @karambit You can learn about the syntax in the expression `((x, True):)` [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator). Basically, you can omit either the left or right input of an operator and the result is a function of the remaining input. Actually, you can omit both (e.g. `(:)`), which allows you to use the operator as you would a function.